# Problem when transcribing R code into Python

Tags: python, r

I am currently working on translating the R code into Python and ran into some problems.

In the original R code, I first ran the following codes to generate a simulated dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(n = 200, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- x^5 - 2 * x^4 + x^3 + rnorm(n = 200, sd=0.01)
```

Then, I fitted a seventh degree polynomial model using the following:

```
seventh_degree<-lm(formula=y~poly(x, degree=7), data=df)
summary(seventh_degree)
```

In this summary output, there are total of five variables that are significant (first degree polynomial through fifth degree)

After, I proceeded to replicate this simple process in Python using the following code:

```
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=7,include_bias=False) 
x_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(df[['x']])  
x_poly = sm.add_constant(x_poly) 
lm_fit = sm.OLS(df['y'], x_poly).fit() print(lm_fit.summary())
```

However, the summary output on Python indicates that none of the variable is significant. The Python code should be replicating the R code, so all variables that were identified as significant on R should appear as significant on Python as well. Any insights into this?

The output on R looks something like this: [image]

The output on Python looks like this: [image]

Conclusions drawn (i.e which variables are significant) should be identical across R and Python,  but as of now, none of the variables in Python appears to be significant for some reason.

Comment: How did you generate the data frame `df` in Python? In R you used `set.seed` for reproducible random values - did you use an equivalent procedure in Python, are the x-values the same?

Comment: The `poly()` function in R calculates orthogonal polynomials by default.  Try with `poly(x, degree = 7, raw = TRUE)` and see if the results match.

Comment: Use the same x values. eg in R `x <- iris['Sepal.Length']` in python `x = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris').data['Sepal.Length']`

Comment: @neilfws I used the following: `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})` to generate the data frame. In lieu of set.seed, I used `np.random.seed(123)`. To replicate the data generating process used in R, I used the following: `x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=200)
y = x**5 - 2 * x**4 + x**3 + np.random.normal(0, 0.01, size=200)`. I hope this clarifies!

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Are you suggesting replacing PolynomialFeatures() with poly()? You are referencing the poly() from the numpy library right?

Comment: @Onyambu are you suggesting me to import the dataset from R to Python? Perhaps I could do that but the discrepancy between Python and R Studio (i.e summary statistics) seems too drastic to be explained by randomness in the data generating process.

Comment: I am suggesting that you use the same dataset in R and in Python. Try for example Running the summary in R 3 times without the seed. you will notte that the significance of each each term does fluctuate highly. Meaning the randomness does matter.

Comment: @Onyambu Fair point. But I think the problem with that approach is that the dataset that I am using here is not from an R package (like the iris dataset). Instead, it's just a random number generated from a simple equation:`set.seed(1)
x <- runif(n = 200, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- x^5 - 2 * x^4 + x^3 + rnorm(n = 200, sd=0.01)` Also, when I tried running the R code without seed, at least few variables were significant. It seems odd to me that on Python, none of the variable is close to being significant.

Comment: try running in python again. i do get some being significant

Comment: try running in python again. i do get 3rd, 4th and 5th variables to be significant

Comment: @BoogieLy - no, I'm suggesting using raw polynomials in R and seeing if it matches the python results.